# How to find a node by name in adobe cq5

Tags: osgi, aem, jcr, osgi-bundle, sling

I am trying to find out the best way to get the Node in repository by its name. I can make sure that no 2 nodes will have the same name in the repository.

I can write a recursive code to get the node by name but that can degrade the system performance if my node is at root --> level 1000 --> level 1k

if Adobe CQ5(CRX) provides any api to do the same?

Comment: You can definitely use a query, as per Tomek's answer below, but to me it feels like you're doing something odd if you need to pull out a random node (never mind even a page) that's 1,000 levels deep — can you really not narrow down your search based on hierarchy? You should definitely aim to structure the hierarchy appropriately if at all possible.

Comment: First off, i dont really understand what do you mean by maintaining a hierarchy here. eventhough i am creating a well defined structure of nodes and need to search for the random node then i think query gonna work for me. ???

Comment: Querying the whole database will work, if you really cannot organise your content tree to avoid it. All I meant was that it's of course going to be slower if you have to search at every level in all parts of the repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a JCR query:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE NAME(s) = '%s'";
resourceResolver.findResources(String.format(query, "node-name"), "JCR-SQL2");
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Awesome!!

Comment: @Tomek, Is there any way through which i can search nodes by starting string of there name.i want to search  all the nodes under given path starting from KB what should be the query. I tried using like and localname() , % but it doesn't work.
Sample nodes are KB1234.KBAB56,KBCH578 . How i can search all nodes whose name starting from KB from XPATH . i have used this query SELECT * FROM [nt:unstructured] As node WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE ([/etc/commerce/products/flr]) AND NAME(node) = 'KB%'